# invalid use of incomplete type, forward declaration not work

Tags: c++, qt

How to fix this invalid use of incomplete type 'class Window'? even with forward declaration still error. I need to use class window  everywhere. Cause, render window will random dependent on situation. Window class have render method.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

class Window;
class MainWindow;

class DashBoardWindow: public QWidget
{
  public:
    DashBoardWindow()
    {
      this->setWindowTitle("Dashboard");
    }
};

class MainWindow: public QWidget 
{
  public:
    MainWindow()
    {
       this->setWindowTitle("MainWindow");

        DashBoardWindow* dash = new DashBoardWindow;
        Window* wnd = new Window;
        wnd->render(dash, this);
    }
};

class Window
{
    public:
    void render(QWidget* widget, QWidget* parent = nullptr)
    {
      if(parent == nullptr){ widget->show(); }
      else{
          widget->show();

          parent->close();

          delete this;
      }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  MainWindow* mainWnd = new MainWindow;
  Window* wnd = new Window;
  wnd->render(mainWnd);

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: `Window* wnd = new Window;` cannot be done without seeing the full class definition. Move that code into a separate implementation file.

Answer (score 2):

A forward declaration is an incomplete definition. You either need to move the complete definition of Window above the code that uses it, or you need to move it to a separate header file and include it (`#include "Window.h"`)

Comment: okay  it fixed it, but now new error show up. candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided in render method. compiler don''t know default argument pointer? if put 2nd argument with nullptr. compile succcess.